# Converting 2d to 1d array and image output. weird results

Tags: javascript, image, math, multidimensional-array

okay. so I'm converting a 2d matrix of pixels into a 1d uint8clampedarray.

```js
class test{
     constructor(x,y){
          this.width=x;
          this.height=y;
          this.data = new uInt8ClampedArray(x*y*4)
     }
     convertMatrixToPixels(){
          const IMAGE = Uint8ClampedArray.from(this.data)
          //convert a regular 2d js array into a 1d clamped array
          let lastNum=-4;//4 away from zero
          for (let y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
               for (let x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                    var pos = (((y * (this.width)) + x) * 4)
                    console.assert(pos==lastNum+4,`weird pos ${pos} and lastNum${lastNum} are not aligned`)
                    //r
                    IMAGE[pos] = 0
                    //g
                    IMAGE[pos + 1] =0
                    //b
                    IMAGE[pos + 2] =0
                    // and opacity
                    IMAGE[pos + 3] = 255;
                    //lastNum recorded for debug
                    lastNum=Number(pos);
               }
          }
          console.assert(lastNum+4 == this.data.length,`"lastNum, this.data.length${lastNum} is that ${this.data.length}"`)
          return IMAGE
     }
}
```

however I get a series of bands when I execute this code.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzDWW.png, sorry (it's tiny... the big version just hurts the eyes)

if the image is too small, the vertical banding is every pixel column - and is in the order of black,red,green,blue... which is a clue to the bug... which must be some sort of miscounting.

so I think it's an off-by-one type of error, I've tried rearranging the ordering of iteration, variations on the calculation of pos... but no dice.

I expect a solid black picture, and as far as I can tell, I am iterating over all the pixels 4 at a time, and not jumping any... so its a bit of a mystery to me where I'm off by one (if that's what's even wrong)

Answer (score 0):

okay. so it turns out the above code was correct, and I was converting using a npm module called sharp. and had the options set to 3 channels instead of 4, (forgot about alpha) so now that accounts for the drift. I was very confused. but I believe the above code to be correct. as it is working as expected now after that change.